# IPC between Qt and C/C++

Tags: c++, qt, ipc

I need to send/receive data between two processes. One of them will be using Qt (4 or 5).
That process will be running all the time (like a background process).

The other process will be launched and then it should be able to send `argv` to the 
first process and receive some `answer` from it.

The second process must startup as fast as possible so using QtCore is kind of a last resourse. Meaning I need it to be as small and fast as possible, so I'd need to use plain 
C/C++ without any external libraries.

Any ideas how it could be done?

If that's not possible, I'll have to use QtCore in the second process. Do you know how much
slower it would be because of QtCore vs plain C/C++? (in terms of startup time).

Regards

EDIT:

I can't use QBus as this must be Mac/Linux/Windows compatible.

Comment: Why not just write the Qt process as a conventional server and have it listen on a port that any client can just connect to? There's no good cross-platform IPC mechanism built into C or C++ without "external libraries", but things like libcurl are much lighter than Qt if you just need a quick bit of network support without needed to customize the code for each platform.

Comment: @deong you mean make use of QSocket and then just read/write to/from it?

Comment: @cmannett85 no, no Boost. It's as heavy as QtCore

Comment: Yes, you can use a QSocket on the server. On the client, any way of writing and reading to/from a socket works fine. Also, @cmannett85, Boost is typically pretty light at runtime.

Comment: @deong I didn't suggest it wasn't.  I was just asking for more information about the OP's application.

Comment: "It's as heavy as QtCore" - Many boost classes are just header-only (templates) - then you pay only for what you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it needs to be fully cross platform compatible your best bet is likely to be named sockets/named pipes, which should work on each platform. [Should take you to the information you need](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ipc.html#tcp-ip) for the socket setup. You'll still need some network handling code in your pure C++ application, but it should be significantly less overhead than Qt-Core and Qt-Network.

You could also do it with shared memory, but I prefer the socket method for simplicity.

Comment: I think I'll go with sockets. Thank you :)